# Sum of function values in two points in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

The task is to compute `f(2) + f(10)` in tensorflow. One of the ways is

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
f = x ** 2

sess = tf.Session()
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)
a = sess.run(f, feed_dict={x: 2})
b = sess.run(f, feed_dict={x: 10})
c = a + b
print(c)
```

But `a + b` is Python operation, not tensorflow. The question is how to define that operation in tf? I can't understand how to define two nodes in computational grph which correspond to values of the same function in different points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since for `f(2) + f(10)`, you need to feed two parameters, you'll have to define two *placeholders* as well:

```
# define two placeholders
a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
b = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
​
def f(x):
    return x ** 2
​
c = f(a) + f(b)                              # this is the tf operation

sess = tf.Session()    ​
c = sess.run(c, feed_dict={a: 2, b: 10})
print(c)
# 104.0
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to do it without defining function? My task is more difficult and I reformulate it in such way.

Comment: You don't have to define a function. I am not sure what your real set up is, but `c = a ** 2 + b ** 2` should work as well here.